# Android Tablets and Software Buttons, Menu gets no touches

Tags: android, menu, touches

First of all.. I'm fairly new to the Android world (I'm expanding from just iOS Development) and have done a fair share of research on the internet but am kind of stumped with this one..

My App is a fairly basic app, the MainActivity consists of a MapActivity and a Menu..

The test devices that I have here are as follows:

- HTC One X - 4.0.4 - Hardware Back/Home/Multitasking - Software Menu
- Asus Nexus 7 - 4.2.1 - Software Back/Home/Multitasking/Menu
- Huawei Ascend G 300 - 2.3.6 - Hardware Back/Home/Menu

My App appears to work fine on all of these devices and I sent over a build to my Client to test out..

His Device is as follows:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab "10 - 3.1 - Software Back/Home/Multitasking/Menu

The app appears to launch fine for him but as soon as he clicks the software menu (the overflow), he is presented with the 3 buttons (Search, History and Settings) however once tapped there is no response, not even a selected image to indicate the press is being received!

I run the Android Emulator on the same specs and can re-create the issue (using the "10.1in WXGA (Tablet)" template).. Also when a map annotation is pressed it does the same and don't respond to touches...

My Min SDK version is 10
My Target SDK version is 17

I also ran a 320x480 device on 3.1 (had hardware buttons) and there was no issue (no issue with the touches on the MapView either) so this made me try a 10" tablet with hardware buttons..

I then cloned the "10.1in WXGA (Tablet)" template in the AVD Manager and changed the software buttons to hardware, to see what happened but it ignored them and still presented software buttons..

I then ran the "10.1in WXGA (Tablet)" template on 4.2 and it ran just like my physical Nexus 7 with no issues so that rules out 10" tablets being the issue..

This has really left me stumped as I'm running out of ideas on how to solve this issue so I'm using this as my last resort..

Here is my Menu XML (I left the settings as an overflow for testing purposes as I will be using if room on the live version)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_search" android:enabled="true" android:checkable="false" android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_history"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_history" android:enabled="true" android:checkable="false" android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings" android:enabled="true" android:checkable="false" android:visible="true"/></menu>
```

and here are the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and  `onOptionsItemSelected()` functions..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    Log.i("NOTE","Menu Item Pressed: "+item.getItemId());
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_search:
            showSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_history:
            Intent history = new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(history, HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        default:
            Intent settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settings);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Just a side note, the apps build target is the Google APIs 4.2 (API 17)

If you need anymore information please let me know and I will supply it.. I also should remind you that this bug also effects selecting an Overlay on the PolarisMapView library so it may not just be localised to the Menu.

The other two MenuItems that are shown in the ActionBar also work fine.. it seems to be just when its displayed in the overflow box... Also navigation around the map works fine so the map is getting touch events for most parts..

Here is the layout of my MainActivity as well as it may be relavent:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.cyrilmottier.polaris.PolarisMapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:apiKey="MY API KEY HERE" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adsdkContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for reading people!

Comment: Try to set target SDK to 10

Comment: @AliImran That forces the menu down to the bottom bar however doesn't seem to fix the main issues (touches still don't function correctly on the MapView)